# Find the zeros of $f(x)=x^3+64$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$f(x)=x^3+64$$ 
Again, I am really not sure how to do this I tried to factor but it clearly was not the right answer

Comment: Mind your tags, please. The appropriate tag here is `[algebra-precalculus]`

Comment: This seems to be the third question you've posted that is along these lines in the last hour. This site isn't here to solve your homework for you! We'd love to try and help you to understand *how* to solve these problems, but to do this we need to know what you've tried. How did you try to factorise this? Can you see any zeros by observation?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Sorry. I am new to this site

Comment: You should get informed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) then.

Comment: Voting to reopen -- the question is **not** how to factor the polynomial, but how to find its zeroes. The OP says he tried to factor it as a possible approach, but that doesn't mean that "how to factor" is the question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:$a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)$

Comment: Other examples of this type of factoring would be
$$\begin{array}{}
x^3+a^3 = (x+a)(x^2-ax+a^2)\\
x^5+a^5 = (x+a)(x^4-ax^3+a^2x^2-a^3x+a^4)\\
x^7+a^7 = (x+a)(x^6-ax^5+a^2x^4-a^3x^3+a^4x^2-a^5x+a^6)\\
\end{array}$$

Try multiplying these vertically. This is a good video that describes the vertical multiplication process (without resorting to satanic chants like "FOIL"). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvpUp8OCMRA . Multiplying vertically is the clearest way of seeing how all of the middle terms magically cancel out.

Answer (score 2):

$x^3 + 64 = x^3+4^3 = (x+4)(x^2-4x+16) = (x+4)((x-2)^2+12) = 0 \to x+4 = 0 \to x= -4$. I suppose you want real roots. If you want complex roots, then $(x-2)^2 = -12 = (2\sqrt{3}\cdot i)^2 \to x = 2 \pm 2\sqrt{3}\cdot i$.

In general, if you are interested in finding the roots of $p(x) = x^3 + q$, then you first write: $p(x) = x^3 + (\sqrt[3]{q})^3 = (x+\sqrt[3]{q})(\cdots)$

Answer (score 1):

It's not half as complicated as the other answers make it look -- factoring the polynomial is (in this case) a pointless detour when you just want the roots.

You want to find $x$ such that $$x^3+64=0$$
Subtract 64 on both sides to get
$$ x^3 = -64 $$
We can stop here and say $x=\sqrt[3]{-64}$ ... but in case you don't know how to take cube roots of negative numbers, we can negate both sides:
$$ -(x^3) = 64 $$
and note that $-(x^3)$ happens to be the same as $(-x)^3$, so
$$ (-x)^3 = 64 $$
$$ -x = \sqrt[3]{64} = 4 $$
and finally negate once more to find
$$ x = -4 $$

Comment: Is it obvious (at a precalculus level) that there is only one real root?

Comment: @Mathmo123: I think at the $x^3=-64$ stage it should be fairly obvious -- even for "precalculus" one ought to have seen the graph of $x^3$ and know that it is injective (on the reals).

Comment: Agreed, although being able to factorise a polynomial like this isn't a bad skill to have, and knowing that it can be factorised will make things much easier when complex numbers are introduced.

Answer (score 0):

At the precalculus level, any cubic polynomial (i.e. a function of the form $f(x) = ax^3 + b x^2 + cx + d$) that you are asked to find the roots of will almost certainly have one "obvious root".

In this example, can you find a value of $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$ - i.e. $$x^3 = -64$$

Once you have this one root, let's call it $a$, you can use this root to find the other roots by factorising the cubic. Since $f(a) = 0$, by the Remainder Theorem, we know that $f$ has $(x-a)$ as a factor. So find $b, c$ such that $$f(x) = (x-a)(x^2 +bx + c)$$ and you're left with a quadratic to factorise. The roots of $f$ are then just $a$ and the roots of the quadratic equation $x^2 + bx +c$, which you can solve in the usual way.